# How to call a function from another one with optional third parameter?

Tags: python, string, parameter-passing

I'm learning python from [this tutorial](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/). I'm trying to solve 3rd exercise (under 7.16. Exercises, on [this page](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch07.html)). If anybody can help me and give some tips because it's not that I don't know how, but I'm not sure I get what actually I have to do ("HOW TO DO" is not the problem, problem is "WHAT TO DO").

This is the code I have so far (from the 2nd exercise, since these two exercises are linked):

```
def count_letters(string, letter):
    count = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == letter:
            count+=1
    print count
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Did you read the [*Optional parameters* section](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch07.html#optional-parameters) the exercise links you to? What does your `count_letters` function from exercise 2 look like? Please include your own efforts in your question.

Comment: I have included it now. Everything works perfect, as I said. My problem is I don't understand what I have to do in this 3rd exercise (Other exercises I understood completely and I have done them fine).

Comment: The question is asking you for an iterative solution that moves the starting position of the search up the string until the string is exhausted. That's about as much help as I can be without writing code.

Note that many string search functions take a (usually optional) starting index as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **optional parameter** is a parameter you can either provide or leave out, in the latter case, there's a default value assigned.

Given the second find in http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch07.html#optional-parameters

```
def find(strng, ch, start=0):
```

`start` is an optional parameter. In case you in invoke `find` like

```
find('foobar', 'o')
```

`start` is implicitly set to 0, thus `find` starts finding at index 0, thus at the beginning of that string, in case you invoke it like

```
find('foobar', 'o', 3)
```

`start = 3` would we used, and try start finding letter 'o' at index 3 (and fail).

---

Exercise 7.16.3 simply wants you to find starting at 0, get the index for the first match, use that index to figure out a new value to continue searching at, find again... and repeat and count matches until the find fails.

Answer (score 2):

The *optional third parameter* refers to the `start` parameter of the [`string.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method that allows you to specify the starting index for the search.